# GCP policy inheritance understanding conflict

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to this https://medium.com/@bekahlundy/google-cloud-platform-fundamentals-for-aws-professionals-week-2-bbee857472f5
Policies are a union of those applied on the resource itself and those inherited from higher levels in the hierarchy. If a parent policy is **less** restrictive, it overrides a more restrictive policy applied on the resource. If a parent policy is **more** restrictive, it does not override a less restrictive policy applied on the resource. Therefore, access granted at a higher level in the hierarchy cannot be taken away by policies applied at a lower level in the hierarchy.

But according to the diagram here https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/understanding-hierarchy
Parent allows red+green, child denies green, and the result is red?

Seems to conflict. Appreciate any input.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article in Medium refers to the [Roles in IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) while the GCP documentation you are looking at is referring to the [Custom policy](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles).

The article in Medium is still correct since it is referring to a pre defined role which is the `Owner`.